# Pivot table with another pivot table design in MySQL and Laravel Elequent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

What is better design to join pivot table has another child pivot table.

1. I have award department pivot table with `award_id` and `department_id`.
2. Auditor will be assigned to the award in department wise. [only award departments]

I designed as follows,

[image]

Do you suggest any improvement in MySQL.?

In Laravel eloquent  model, How can I write these relations?

Comment: Can you describe the earlier relations to `award_department`? To me, it sounds like you don't need a second pivot, but rather re-thinking the structure prior to it. That said, have you seen Eloquent's `hasManyThrough` relation?

Comment: I have `awards` and `departments` table. then I want to allocate each award in each department. that is `award_department`

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your models